# Plotting multiple markers on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude, markers

If I have a object containing lats and longs how can i plot them in Leaflet using the marker constructor I tried looping through them

```js
for(key in obj){
            var val = obj[key];
            var markers = new L.Marker([val.lat, val.long]);
            map.addLayer(markers);
        }
```

but its not showing up in the map

```js
var obj ={
 0 : {
        lat: 15.606562000000000
        long: 32.513681000000000
    },
1 : {
        lat: -12.09137
        long: 34.7182
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not using the [`L.Marker` constructor](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#marker).

> Constructor: `L.Marker( <LatLng> latlng, <Marker options> options? )`

And a [`L.LatLng` is](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#latlng):

> Constructor: `L.LatLng( <Number> latitude, <Number> longitude)`

So:

```
var markers = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(val.lat, val.long));
```

---

Additional JS tips:

1. `markers` should be `marker`, as it is a reference to a single marker.
2. If your indices are incremental numbers, you should consider making `obj` an array, and use a `for` loop instead of a `for-in`. If not, use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: And an additional tip: Don't use the global variable `var` for a variable that is only being used inside the loop. Better use `let` (for a variable that is reassigned inside the block scope) or `const` (for a constant that is not reassigned - like `val` or `marker`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var locations = [
       ["Locations 1", 6.625117, 39.145004],
       ["Locations 2", -6.5767859, 39.1304557],
       ["Locations 3", -6.8667841, 39.2530337],
       ["Locations 4", -6.7787336, 39.2273218],
       ["Locations 5", -6.7576158, 39.2768276],
];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]])
             .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
             .addTo(mymap);
}
```

Comment: I did just like Shedrack showed, the only difference is I have my map in script tag in HTML and array is made in JavaScript. How can I display the points on map using that array?

Comment: @HalfSparrow, you will need to reference the array from the JavaScript file into the HTML  file. Then you should be able to use it as seen above.